# Make a the same metric topology with a new metric on it by a continuous function

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

The question I am working on is:
***Question:** X is a metric space. All metrics that makes this topology on $X$ are bounded. Prove that all continuous real functions on this space are bounded too.*
**My attempt:**
Assume $X$ is the metric space with $d$ as its metric. I want to make another metric on this space by using the continuous function $\Phi:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_1: &X\times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \\
& x \times y \mapsto (\Phi(x), \Phi(y))
\end{aligned}
$$
I want to show that $f_1$ is continuous. As we know for proving a continuous function ob the product space we only need to prove that each $f: X\times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with the definition for each $x \times y$ that $f(x \times y )=\Phi(x)$ or $\Phi(y)$. This function is continuous because all of opens $U$ in $\mathbb{R}$ has a image like $\Phi^{-1}(U)\times Y$. As a result, we have $f_1$ is a continuous function, and the following functions is continuous too because it is from two continous functions $f_1$ and  the metric on $\mathbb{R}$.
$$\begin{aligned}
f_2: &X\times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}   \\
& x \times y \mapsto |\Phi(x)- \Phi(y)|
\end{aligned}$$
I want to make the metric $\varphi$ on $X$ as following:
$$\begin{aligned}
\varphi: &X\times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}   \\
& x \times y \mapsto Max\{|\Phi(x)- \Phi(y)|,d(x,y)\}
\end{aligned}$$
As it is the maximum of two continuous function it should be continuous itself. We should check that this function makes a metric on $X$. 
**Lemma 1:** $\varphi$ is a metric on $X$.
*Proof.*

1. It is always positive as it is the maximum of two positive functions.
2. if $\varphi(x \times y)=0$ so we should have $d(x\times y) =0 \implies x=y$.
3. the triangle inequality:
   $$\varphi(x \times y)+ \varphi(y \times z)=Max\{|\Phi(x)- \Phi(y)|,d(x,y)\}+Max\{|\Phi(y)- \Phi(z)|,d(y,z)\} \ge Max\{|\Phi(x)- \Phi(z)|,d(x,z)\}=\varphi(x \times z)$$
   $\blacksquare$

At the end we should show that this metric on the space makes the same topology as $d$.
**Lemma 2:** The topology on $X$ by the metric $\varphi$ is finer than the metric $d$.
*Proof.*

We show that for each $x \in X$ and each open basis ball $B_d(x,\varepsilon)$ then $B_{\varphi}(x,\frac{\varepsilon}{2})$ is in the $B_d(x,\varepsilon)$.
$$\begin{aligned}
B_{\varphi}(x,\frac{\varepsilon}{2}) &=\{y|\varphi(x\times y) \lt  \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \} \\
&=\{y||\Phi(x) - \Phi(y)| \lt  \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \;\text{and}\; d(x,y) \lt \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\} \\
&= B_d(x,\frac{\varepsilon}{2}) \cap \Phi^{-1}((\Phi(x)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2},\Phi(x)+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}))
\end{aligned}$$
$\blacksquare$

It is obviously coarser that the topology on $X$ by $d$ too, As all of opens it the metric topology $\varphi$ on $X$ are opens in the original $X$ too.

Now as the metric $\varphi$ should be bounded, the exists $M$ that $\varphi(x\times y) \le M$. Assume $x_0 \in X$ constant then:
$$\forall x \in X \rightarrow \varphi(x\times x_0) \le M \rightarrow |\Phi(x)-\Phi(x_0)| \le M \implies -M+\Phi(x_0) \le \Phi(x) \le M+\Phi(x_0)$$
As a result. $\Phi$ is bounded too.

My Questions:

1. Firstly, Is my proof correct or am I missing something?
2. Is there any other functions to do the task for us?

If you have any other solution let me know. I love to know new ways of solving a question.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $f: X \to \Bbb R$ is continuous on $(X,d)$ then $d'(x,y)=d(x,y) + |f(x)-f(y)|$ is a compactible metric on $X$ too.

$d'$ is bounded by assumption so $f$ is too.

Comment: Your $d'(x,y)=\max(d(x,y), |f(x)-f(y)|)$ is I think also possible, but I believe the sum metric is easier.

Comment: You could also prove as an intermediate step that $X$ is compact.